# Dynamic variable assignment based on vector element values in Octave

Tags: dynamic, octave, variable-assignment

I need to dynamically assign variable names to each row in a matrix based on the element values of the row so that I can later reference the appropriate row based on the variable rather than an index value.
I am having trouble identifying how to store the variable name along with its associated vector so that the vector can be later pulled up by simply typing in the variable name. 
So far, using a simplified example I have:

```
A = [1 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 1];
s = cell(rows(A),1)
i = 1;
for i = 1:rows(A)
       if (A(i,1) == 1 & A(i,2) == 1 & A(i,3) == 0) s(i,1) = struct("x1_y1_z0",{A(i,:)})
   elseif (A(i,1) == 1 & A(i,2) == 0 & A(i,3) == 1) s(i,1) = struct("x1_y0_z1",{A(i,:)})
   elseif (A(i,1) == 0 & A(i,2) == 1 & A(i,3) == 1) s(i,1) = struct("x0_y1_z1",{A(i,:)});
    endif
    i++
endfor
```

However, the resulting structue s lists x1_y1_z0 = 1 1 0 in a cell [1,1] and s.x1_y1_z0 does not return [1 1 0] as I would like.
Thanks very much for your guidance towards a working solution.

Comment: Just write `struct("x1_y1_z0", A(i,:))` without the `{}`. Having said that, capturing otherwise perfectly indexable structures by bespoke variable names is literally the worst idea ever though. Also, note that `&` is the 'elementwise conjunction' operator; you probably meant for the boolean shortcut operator `&&`. Also you can just do something like `if (A(i,:) == [1 1 0])`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Agreed that creating bespoke variables makes life difficult.  However, it's necessary in order to have a way in which to reference one of many vectors where indexing will not suffice.  Thanks again for your response.

Comment: This is still an indexing operation though. Instead, I would suggest a cell structure of as many dimensions as variables, with a size two for each dimension (representing 1 and 0). i.e. for three variables: `C = cell(2,2,2)`. Then you could call the contents of "x1y0z1" as `C{1,2,1}`. (if the '1,2' instead of '1,0' bothers you, you can write a quick anonymous function, e.g. `getC = @(subs) -(subs-2)`.  Otherwise, if you're sticking with the struct method, at least make each level a field of its own, i.e. `S.x1.y0.z1 = [1,0,1]` rather than `S.x1y0z1`. Otherwise, good luck getting all `x1`s.